# Subtracting two bags/relations in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two identical bags or relations (have same fields), say B1 and B2. I want to subtract B2 from B1 so that I get all those tuples that are in B1 but not in B2. The SUBTRACT function in Pig subtracts fields but I am looking for tuple subtraction like the 'difference' or 'minus' operators in SQL.

Example: Bag/Relation R1 has following tuples

```
(a1, b1)
(a2, b2)
(a3, b3)
(a4, b4)
```

Relation R2 has following tuples

```
(a1, b1)
(a2, b2, d2)
(a3, b3, d3)
(a4, b4)
```

I would like to obtain the following Relation/Bag containing:

```
(a1, b1)
(a4, b4)
```

Comment: The question asked how to get subtracting, but I feel the example is saying how to get join set.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this:

```
table1 = load './subtract1.dat' USING PigStorage(',') as (c1, c2);
table2 = load './subtract2.dat' USING PigStorage(',') as (d1, d2, d3);

cgrp = cogroup table1 by (c1, c2), table2 by (d1, d2);

subtract = filter cgrp by IsEmpty(table2);
substract_flatten = FOREACH subtract GENERATE FLATTEN(table1);

dump subtract_flatten;
```

Got the idea from http://agiletesting.blogspot.in/2012/02/set-operations-in-apache-pig.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
You can use PIG `JOIN` operations in order to perform the functions like difference,minus and so on.
Refer here to know about Left outer join for your difference operation

```
http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/04/07/real-world-hadoop---implementing-a-left-outer-join-in-pig.html
```